# Is it safe to modify an array while looping it?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is it safe to modify an array while looping it, such as push an element?

I'm using underscore each method

Comment: Generally not, but it would be helpful to see a snippet of your code, so that we can determine the exact answer for your use case.

Comment: Not sure about Underscore, but in general libraries that provide iteration methods tend to cache the array length and thus get confused if you add or remove elements while iterating. But it's not difficult to substitute a traditional for loop and manage the index variable yourself.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right, if you look at the underscore source code, it gets the keys of the object BEFORE it manipulates it. In this case, it would know how many elements to iterate through before you changed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend avoid `each` unless you absolutely need to cause a side effect for every item in a collection (trigger an event, print out a result, etc.). For simply modifying your collection, there are better ways.

If each added element is only the result of an individual input element, the typical functional pattern would be to `flatmap` the array, which can be thought of a two steps:

1. Using `map` to apply a function that for each element generates an array as a result. The overall result will be an array of arrays.
2. Using `flatten` on that array of arrays to get a one dimensional array.

Using [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/) or [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs):

```
var origArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var duplicateIf3 = function (val) { return val === 3 ? [val, val] : val; };
_.flatten(origArray.map(duplicateIf3));
// -> [1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

(In typed FP, the function would have to return `[val]` for values that aren't 3, but `flatten` doesn't care--it flattens whatever you give it to one dimension.)

If the new element is dependent on all that came before it, you would probably use a `reduce` or `fold` instead, with the empty array as the initial value.

```
var origArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
origArray.reduce(function (acc, val) { return acc.concat(acc).concat(val); }, []);
// -> [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

(Sorry I couldn't think of a realistic example, but here every step uses the full output of all previous steps in a pretty simple way for illustrative purposes, and you can see from each value of the original array what's going on. Also note that you can make your own  `flatten` from `reduce`, if you don't want to use underscore/lodash)

`reduce` is more general than `flatmap`, but both methods are able to convert an array into a larger array that some how depends on the first one.

If you're interested in learning more about this, I highly recommend checking out the free (online) [Javascript Allongé](https://leanpub.com/javascript-allonge), by Reg Braithwaite.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by safe, but you'd have to have a good reason to do it. I played around with it a bit, and here's what I got:

```
_.each(a, function(el) { 
    if (el % 2 == 0) 
        a.push(el + 1); 
    console.log(el); 
});

// logs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

console.log(a);
// logs [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5 ]
```

In this case, there is no negative affect unless you wanted to go through the added elements, but you could find yourself in trickier situations if you're changing the specific elements:

```
_.each(a, function(el, index) { 
    a[index + 1] = el - 1;
    if (el % 2 == 0) 
        a.push(el + 1); 
    console.log(el); 
});

// logs 1, 0, -1, -2, -3
```

It would make more sense to use `_.map` for most use cases.

Comment: Pretty sure this wouldn't be safe for, say, .splice(), however.